# How to link Facebook Messenger to the Mac OS built-in Messages App in 2016?

Tags: macos, mac, facebook, jabber, ichat

Before last year, we can receive Facebook Messenger messages in the Messages app via Jabber, which is super convenient.

However Facebook does not provide Jabber API anymore. I am wondering whether there are some other ways to receive Facebook messages in Messages, rather than using Facebook web or other third party Apps?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately at this point in time there is no way to receive Facebook messages in another application, and certainly not Messages.

You could try [Messenger for Mac](https://fbmacmessenger.rsms.me/), which seems to just base itself off of https://www.messenger.com.